# Error regarding android studio gradle build

Tags: java, android

Basically i am getting an error name
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivservuce.DefaultLenientConfigurations$ArtifactResolveException:couldnot resolve all the files for configuration':app:debugCompileClasspath'

I was trying to practice navigation fragments in android studio.I deleted the older fragments like gallery,slideshow and others and added the new one as according to the tutorial i watched.  Before doing so it was running after i added new one i got error which i mentioned in the first paragraph

Comment: can you include the image of the error or which part of the code it gets error or your gradle code for better reference?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.